# JavaScript: how to build simple percentage increaser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to build increase value as percentage **without progress bar**.

I have built an animator, but actually I need simple one which show value from `0%` to `100%` without progress bar or anything.

Here is my code:

```
$('.progress-bar').animate(
    {width:'83%'}, 
    {
        duration:2000,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            if(fx.prop == 'width') {
                $(this).html(Math.round(now * 100) / 100 + '%');
            }
        }
    }        
);
```

**Progress bar not needed just `<p></p>` only**

I know this is not the way for it, my JavaScript knowledge is really low :(

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/zjdBh/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FOR UPDATED QUESTION**

You could use an interval:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zjdBh/11/)

```
var value = 0,
    interval = setInterval(function(){
    value = ((+value) + .1).toFixed(1);
    if(value == 80.5) clearInterval(interval);   
    $('p').html(value+'%');
},2);
```

**FIRST POST**

Is it what you are looking for?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zjdBh/3/)

```
$('.progress-bar').animate(
    {width:'100%'}, 
    {
        duration:2000,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            if(fx.prop == 'width') {
                var newval = Math.round(now * 100) / 100 + '%';
                $([this,$(this).nextAll('p')[0]]).html(newval);
            }
        }
    }        
);
```

Comment: any option without progress bar? sorry for the misunderstanding of my question

Comment: Seriously, you should not edit your question 15 min after by changing completly what you are looking for. Now all answers are just obsoletes.

Comment: I am really sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't need progress bar or any thing just one `<p>` which show 0 to 100% that's. From my research I have found one progress bar which I put in question :(

Comment: Can I end with `85.8%` like this ? `if(value === 80.5) clearInterval(interval);`

Answer (score 2):

i have updated my answer please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zjdBh/4/)

====================================================='

it's really  cool progress bar..

i have used this type of progress bar..

please check below  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3h83c/1/)  may be it will solve your problem.

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.animateProgress = function(progress, callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        width: progress+'%'
      }, {
        duration: 2000,

        easing: 'swing',

        step: function( progress ){
          var labelEl = $('.ui-label', this),
              valueEl = $('.value', labelEl);

          if (Math.ceil(progress) < 20 && $('.ui-label', this).is(":visible")) {
            labelEl.hide();
          }else{
            if (labelEl.is(":hidden")) {
              labelEl.fadeIn();
            };
          }

          if (Math.ceil(progress) == 100) {
            labelEl.text('Done');
            setTimeout(function() {
              labelEl.fadeOut();
            }, 1000);
          }else{
            valueEl.text(Math.ceil(progress) + '%');
          }
        },
        complete: function(scope, i, elem) {
          if (callback) {
            callback.call(this, i, elem );
          };
        }
      });
    });
  };
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
  $('#progress_bar .ui-progress .ui-label').hide();
  $('#progress_bar .ui-progress').css('width', '7%');

  $('#progress_bar .ui-progress').animateProgress(43, function() {
    $(this).animateProgress(79, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#progress_bar .ui-progress').animateProgress(100, function() {
          $('#main_content').slideDown();
        });
      }, 2000);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Nice example :) this might be useful for me in future thanks. Here I need to show increase value without progress bar :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/zjdBh/7/ this `<p>` needs to be 0% to 100% (no progress bar needed)